# Gradle compileJava faills sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthenticationCallback

Tags: java, gradle, ntlm-authentication

I'm using `sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthenticationCallback` in a Java file.

The code builds and runs fine from Idea, but fails when using gradle compileJava.

I'm getting this error:

```
D:\source\msnavclient\MsNavClient.java:5: error: package sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm does not exist
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthenticationCallback;
                                     ^
D:\source\msnavclient\MsNavClient.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        NTLMAuthenticationCallback.setNTLMAuthenticationCallback(new NTLMAuthenticationCallback()
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class NTLMAuthenticationCallback
  location: class MsNavClient
D:\source\msnavclient\MsNavClient.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        NTLMAuthenticationCallback.setNTLMAuthenticationCallback(new NTLMAuthenticationCallback()
        ^
  symbol:   variable NTLMAuthenticationCallback
  location: class MsNavClient
3 errors
```

I've found `NTLMAuthenticationCallback` class is in `jre/lib/rt.jar`, and tried adding the dependency directly in `build.gradle` file, but the problem persist.

This is the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // compile files('C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131\\jre\\lib\\rt.jar')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is advisable, but try using the following (from [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-set-compiler-options/10188)). Using it worked for me in a quick example of the issue:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-XDignore.symbol.file", "-Xdoclint:none", "-Xlint:none", "-nowarn"]
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Staring from @michael-easter answer, I found the compileJava task does not use the same procedure javac uses. And found this workarround to have rt.jar included in the classpath:

```
compileJava {
    options.bootClasspath = "${System.env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar"
}
```